# How to find the MAX value from multiple cells containing strings, after a certain character?

Tags: google-sheets, max, extract, average, spreadsheet

I have data that looks like this in Google Sheets:

[image: Data]

What I am trying to do is, get the numbers after the forward slash, and find the maximum and average of them. For example, with this data, the max would return 126. I'm wondering if there is way to loop through the values with a Regex selection, to find the max and average.

I have tried using Regex from Google searching, but nothing has looped through multiple values when trying to find a max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try MAX:

```
=INDEX(MAX(1*IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A4; "\/(\d+)"))))
```

[image]

and AVERAGE:

```
=INDEX(AVERAGE(1*IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A4; "\/(\d+)"))))
```

[image]

Comment: @katherine answer updated. try now